# How to execute files with an ".install" extension?

Tags: files, ruby

### Ubuntu 16

I'm currently trying to install Shoes GUI, and downloaded [the Shoes for Linux file](http://shoesrb.com/downloads/) which has an .install extension, but double-clicking the file does nothing. I thought of the `.install` file as an `.sh` but the following command:

```
sudo ./shoes-3.3.6-gtk3-x86_64.install
```

gives an error:

```
sudo: ./shoes-3.3.6-gtk3-x86_64.install: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the file have executable permissions? You may need to do

`sudo chmod +x shoes-3.3.6-gtk3-x86_64.install`

Also are you sure you are in the correct working directory?